# LaTex serif fonts not working on Pandoc

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pandoc, sans-serif

I have some documents in markdown that I'm trying to convert to PDF using the default latex-engine, pdflatex. This is on a CentOS 7.9.

In the markdown minimal example file, I have a yaml header which is as follows

```
---
title: First Last
fontfamily: sans
...

Heading
=======
```

For converting, I'm using

```
pandoc --latex-engine=pdflatex README.md -o README.pdf
```

The above command works without producing any errors, however, the resulting PDF has the default serif font used by Pandoc's LaTeX (Latin Modern). I'm in no way able to change from Latin Modern Roman to [Computer Modern Sans Serif](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermodernsansserif/). I'm a bit confused as to what settings I need in the yaml header to get the desired results.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: You seem to have some terminology confusion between _sans serif_ and _serif_ fonts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif Can you please correct that in your question statement? As it stands it is very hard to understand what you intend. Actual sans serif fonts are `\sffamily`, not `\rmfamily` in LaTeX. But I am not sure what the configuration for Pandoc should be.

Comment: By saying `fontfamily: sans` you're telling it to set the text in *sans serif*. I imagine if you take that line out, you'll get the desired results.

Comment: You don't need to specify the latex engine flag: pdflatex is the default, just as you say...

Comment: Sorry, if I was confusing. I'm trying to achieve the below font in my PDFs. https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermodernsansserif/

Comment: By saying `fontfamily: sans` you are asking Pandoc to load `sans.sty` to setup the fontfamily, but that package does not exist, afaik. In fact, I don't know why it does not throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The default template for Pandoc's interface through `fontfamily` requires a `sty` file to load the relevant font information from `fd` files (as in, say, `mathpazo.sty`, for instance: so you type `fontfamily: mathpazo`); and the default engine is already `pdflatex`, so you don't need to specify it as a flag in the CLI command. So, to achieve your results you may simply say

```
---
title: First Last
header-includes: \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
...

Heading
=======
```

Use `\renewcommand*` as above to keep Roman available elsewhere, or `\let\rmdefault\sfdefault` instead of `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}` if you want to override completely the Roman font.

And for converting,

```
pandoc README.md -o README.pdf
```

Beware we are not setting up `Computer Modern Sans Serif` strictly, but the `Latin Modern Sans Serif` variant, which is the default for Pandoc. You may see the differences in [another page of the Catalog](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/cmssfonts.html)

You may profit from retrieving the template for LaTeX output by typing `pandoc -D latex` and studying the output.

Comment: Thank you! That worked beautifully

Comment: tip of the day: click the tick for the best answer, if many: you earn trust and we earn reputation (that's the way this site works: I did not design it).

Comment: @jarnosz: if I follow your suggestion and set `header-includes: \let\rmdefault\sfdefault\familydefault{\sfdefault} ` I then have an error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: I see; perhaps I did not state the instructions clearly.

Comment: try again now...